# Odin's Smite card and Thor's Primacy card and Heimdall's Watch

Tags: blood-rage

player A and B are in battle

1- player A plays Odin's Smite  card(Destroy one warrior from each opponent in this province before comparing STR) and player B plays Heimdall's Watch  card(Discard all revealed cards. Gain glory equal to the total +STR revealed. Then Play new cards) 
Now what happen ?
Which card will be used ?

2- player A plays Thor's Primacy card (Cancel the text of each opponent's reveled card before it takes effect) and player B plays Heimdall's Watch  card (Discard all revealed cards. Gain glory equal to the total +STR revealed. Then Play new cards) 
Now wha happen ?
which card will be used ?

3- player A plays Thor's Primacy  card (Cancel the text of each opponent's reveled card before it takes effect) and player B plays Odin's Smite card (Destroy one warrior from each opponent in this province before comparing STR)
what happen now ?
which card will be used ?

Answer (score 2):

The wording on Thor's Primacy makes it clear that it happens first, because it cancels the other cards' text **before** their text takes effect.

Heimdall's Watch clearly has to happen before any "normal" cards, otherwise it would be pointless. "normal" here meaning any card which doesn't specifically affect other cards.

I can see that it's not crystal clear which would take priority out of the two of these cards, but the use of the word "Primacy" meaning *first* or *most important*, and the fact that it specifically says "before" other cards, means that it takes precedence.

So it would make sense if the order of priority was:

1. Thor's Primacy
2. Heimdall's Watch
3. Any other card

This is backed up by [this link](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1443386/order-battle-card-effects-heimdalls-watch-and-odin) and [this link](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1535384/thors-primacy-vs-heimdalls-watch) from boardgamegeek, where Thiago Aranha, apparently one of the game's producers, gives them the same priority.

Answer (score -2):

The cards are to be resolved starting from the pillager and moving clockwise in the following order.
CDE where 
C - cancel cards
D - discard cards
E - every other normal cards

Comment: Can you cite anything to back up that this is how it works, such as a section in the rulebook?

Comment: It can't be both "starting from the pillager and moving clockwise" and "C then D then E". In the vast majority of cases those will be contradictory.

Comment: This applies only to "Some special Battle cards [that] can be used to
further increase the Strength of your troops even after players have revealed their cards.... The
pillaging player has the
first chance to add Strength from one of these special
cards, and it proceeds clockwise around the table
from there until nobody wants to play any. " Heimdall's Eye is an example.  (page 18) . In the example above this type of card would be #4 in order.